# Filter for reverse pairs by value r dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of pairs with the pairs in both orders, e.g. A01-B01, B01-A01.
However I want to keep just one instance of each pair, based on another column.

```
A = c("A01", "A01", "B01", "B02", "C03", "B01")
B = c("A02", "B01", "C03", "C03", "B01", "A01")
C = c(3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3)
df <- tibble(A,B,C)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  A     B         C
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 A01   A02       3
2 A01   B01       4
3 B01   C03       5
4 B02   C03       2
5 C03   B01       5
6 B01   A01       3
```

I want to keep the pair which has the higher value in C. In the case where there is a tie in C, keep the row by alphabetic order for column A.

I was trying to do for part of it

```
df <- df %>% 
  filter(A == B & B == A & C < C)
```

but that isn't working as its stuck (I assume) on the same row. Tried using `%in%`  but that matched too loosely. Haven't quite wrapped my mind around how maybe `rowwise` or `across` would solve the problem.

my expected out put is and would prefer a solution using dplyr pipes to fit in with the rest of my analysis if possible.

```
  A     B         C
1 A01   A02       3
2 A01   B01       4
3 B01   C03       5
4 B02   C03       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I define a group where B01-A01 is put into the A01-B01 group (arbitrarily expressing the pair alphabetically), so we can look at them together. `pmin` is a vectorized `min`, so `pmin(A,B)` will output for each row the smaller (earlier alphabetically) value between what is in A and what is in B.

```
df %>%
  mutate(group = paste(pmin(A,B), pmax(A,B))) %>%
  slice_max(C, by = group, with_ties = FALSE) # "by" from dplyr v1.1.0

# otherwise use: group_by(group) %>% slice_max(C, with_ties = FALSE) %>% ungroup()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  A     B         C group  
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  
1 A01   A02       3 A01 A02
2 A01   B01       4 A01 B01
3 B01   C03       5 B01 C03
4 B02   C03       2 B02 C03
```

Comment: row 4 should be removed since it has the same group as row 3

Comment: We can use the `with_ties = FALSE` if we do not want ties. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sort_and_paste <- function(str1, str2) {
    res <- paste(sort(c(str1, str2)), collapse="-")

    return(res)
}

df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(AB_combined = mapply(sort_and_paste, A, B, SIMPLIFY=F)) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(AB_combined) %>%
    dplyr::slice_max(C) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(A) %>%
    dplyr::distinct(AB_combined, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

First, I define a function to take two strings, sort them, and then paste them together. This serves the function of making (A, B) == (B, A). Then, group by that combined variable and keep the row that has the highest value in C. This still returns duplicates, so we can sort by A and drop duplicates.

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  A     B         C AB_combined
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
1 A01   A02       3 A01-A02    
2 A01   B01       4 A01-B01    
3 B01   C03       5 B01-C03    
4 B02   C03       2 B02-C03
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought this would answer your question.

```
df %>% mutate(
    AB = ifelse(A>B, paste0(B, A), paste0(A, B))) %>% 
    group_by(AB) %>%
    filter(C==max(C)) %>% 
    summarise(across(A:C, first))
```